# Is it possible to use an Android phone with a "Made for iPhone" accessory?

Tags: android, iphone, accessory

I have a car stereo that only accepts a connected iOS device. Is it even possible to somehow create an app/accessory that would allow the stereo to communicate with an Android device?

Comment: this question should be to other site

Comment: mmohab, the question's purpose was about using software to connect to the interface that "Made for iPhone" accessories use. The one in a vehicle often connects via USB and therefore wouldn't need any hardware conversion, it's pure software talking to each other at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the stereo has iOS-specific software and simply getting a converter (Similar to this: [http://www.amazon.com/Iphone-docking-adapter-Atomic-Market/dp/B009RH4N3W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1398717063&sr=8-1&keywords=iphone+to+usb+adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009RH4N3W)) wouldn't work.

However, if the stereo treats it basically as a flash drive, there's potential it could work. I doubt it, though. Including the model of the stereo in your question could help get a more precise answer.